Displacement map $\Delta: C\times C\to TM$ has open image in semi-Riemannian manifold
Hi I’m following o’neill’s book and have the following question regarding the displacement function. Let $M$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold and $C\subset M$ a convex open set (so it is a normal neighbourhood of each of its points). Then, there is a mapping $\Delta:C\times C\to TM$ which is defined, assigning to each pair of points $(p,q)$ the initial velocity $\gamma_{p,q}’(0)$ (also denoted $\vec{pq}$) of the unique geodesic segment $\gamma_{p,q}:[0,1]\to C$ going from $p$ to $q$ and lying entirely in $C$.
O’neill claims (chapter 5, lemma 9) that the image $\Delta(C\times C)$ is open in $TM$, and that it is smooth and that it is the inverse diffeomorphism of $E:\Delta(C\times C)\to C\times C$, where $E$ is defined on the domain of the exponential map as $E(v_p)=(p,\exp_p(v_p))$). However, it is not clear to me why the image set $\Delta(C\times C)$ is open in the first place. Once this is proved, I can apply the inverse function theorem to prove the remaining claims (after noting that $E:\Delta(C\times C)\to C\times C$ and $\Delta:C\times C\to \Delta(C\times C)$ are set-theoretic inverses). Also, O’neill claims this follows by “arguments as above” (referring to the proof of existence of convex neighbourhoods), but I don’t see how they can be adapted here.
So how can i prove the image is open?

Edit: Some further thoughts
I tried to prove that $\Delta(C\times C)$ equals the preimage $E^{-1}(C\times C)$, but I only managed to show $\Delta(C\times C)\subset E^{-1}(C\times C)$. I am unable to show the reverse inclusion: the trouble is that if I take a vector $v_p\in E^{-1}(C\times C)$, then I can certainly consider the geodesic $\gamma(t)=\exp_p(tv_p)$ for $t\in [0,1]$. This geodesic starts at $p\in C$ and ends at $q:=\exp_p(v_p)=(\pi_2\circ E)(v_p)\in C$, but the issue is that I can’t show this lies entirely in $C$. In fact, I wouldn’t be surprised if this is not true, since it’s conceivable that there are multiple geodesics between $p,q$ and only one of them lies in $C$, but perhaps the one we chose is the ‘wrong one’. But perhaps I’m overlooking something and maybe we can salvage this.
Then I came across these online notes and on page 5/6 of the pdf, they give a proof using the inverse function theorem, but I think their proof is flawed, especially when they say “so locally $\Phi=E^{-1}$” (their $\Phi$ is my $\Delta$). I can only see this as reasonable if they already proved that $\Delta(C\times C)$ is open because otherwise, we can’t get that these are inverses to each other locally (all we know is that $E\circ\Delta$ is the identity map on $C\times C$, so all we can conclude is $E|_{\Delta(C\times C)\to C\times C}$ and $\Delta$ are inverse maps, but again, the domain of the former need not be open in $TM$).
I also came across this paper by Valter Moretti, which briefly mentions this result on page 4, in particular, remark 4(3), which makes no sense at all, because the map $\Delta$ has not been proved to be smooth yet, so we can’t even compute its derivative (if we knew it was smooth, then $E\circ \Delta=\text{id}_{C\times C}$ would imply by the chain rule that $\Delta$ is an immersion, and so local diffeomorphism by dimension reasons, and so has open image). So this again feels circular, because I believe the ‘only’ way (in this case) to prove smoothness of $\Delta$ is to somehow establish openness of $\Delta(C\times C)$, and then apply the inverse function theorem to $E$ locally, and then deduce that $E,\Delta$ suitably restricted are inverse diffeomorphisms.
So, both these linked papers I think are wrong, because a correct proof would have to exclude the possibility of the geodesic $t\to\exp_p(tv_p)$ leaving the convex set $C$, as I mentioned in my first paragraph after the edit. Hence my further confusion regarding the proof and even the validity of this supposed statement.
